# If $M_g$ is a genus $0$ surface, why are there no nonseparating curves?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

As the question title suggests, if $M_g$ is a genus $0$ surface, why are there no nonseparating curves?

Comment: Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I'm currently working through some of the problems near the beginning of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, and I need this result for one of the problems. Certainly there's got to be a smaller hammer than that?

Comment: @user374058 either Jordan curve or some form of classification theorem for surface you have to use here. I can't think any easier argument wiothout this. Whatver you tried, in the end, for making a conclusion you've to use either of these two theorem.

Comment: The Jordan curve theorem is a special case of your question, namely the case where the surface is the 2-sphere. So if you want to use a smaller hammer, you'll have to come up with a new proof of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: maybe if the curve is assumed to be smooth, you may use a classification of compact $2$-manifolds with a boundary